# How can I configure tesseract for different font sizes in one line with Python?

Tags: python, configuration, ocr, tesseract

I have a problem that I get only the number 2201 from my image. I have tried all configurations for pytesseract but no result. Maybe somebody here has a solution for me? When I cut the image into two pieces and run the OCR it works perfectly.

```py
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img, lang = 'deu', config='-psm 4')
print(text)
```

that was my configuration

[Image being OCR'd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FnClT.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

Problem is that it short text and it **IS NOT** on one (base)line!
So you will need to split image to 2 part and OCR them separately.

Comment: Thanks for reply. That's what I meant by the statement when I cut the pictures it works perfectly. But i need both information of the image to make key value pears. Is there no way or solution to configure the OCR engine for this issue?